# Vaadin 14 and Push: Accessing Spring SecurityContext and Authentication outside the request thread

Tags: spring, security, vaadin, push

I had the same problem this guy had:
https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/3383122/17008971

When receiving a status from the server I try to refresh content via push (using ui.access) on the client. That content needs the current principal's information.

```
final SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
final Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
```

this

```
authentication
```

is returning null.

He solved this problem using Vaadin Shared Security, but I can't find any repo or library called Vaadin Shared Sec. Are there any other ways to solve the problem?

Comment: The holders are usually only filled per request. It's usually way easier to reason about, if you pass your principal and anything else you need for your async task into the task.

Comment: Are you calling SecurityContextHolder.getContext(); from background thread. If so, it is supposed to return null then. You need to refactor your view logic so, that it handles user related info without your direct call from background thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just get the auth details in the view constructor and make them class-scoped, or have a bean to do that and set its values ? E.g.

```
@Route("some-view")
public class SomeView extends VerticalLayout {
    Authentication authentication;
    private void doHeavyStuff() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1500);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // ignore
        }
    }
    public SomeView() {
        authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        final Button button = new Button("Click me", e -> {
            Notification.show("CLICKED");
            getUI().ifPresent(ui -> {
                ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
                executor.submit(() -> {
                    doHeavyStuff();
                    ui.access(() -> {
                        Notification.show("Calculation done");
                    });
                });
            });
        });
        add(button);
        // simple link to the logout endpoint provided by Spring Security
        Element logoutLink = ElementFactory.createAnchor("logout", "Logout");
        getElement().appendChild(logoutLink);
    }
}
```

I based this answer (tested it as well) in this tutorial, if you want to learn more about it:
https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/securing-your-app-with-spring-security/speciale